# Questions about ktpass/kerberos with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, kerberos

I got a few questions about Kerberos with Active Directory, specifically about the ktpass tool.

---

The example AD I'm using (everything is on 2012R2 level):
*Active Directory* Domain Name: ad.example.com
*Domain Controller*: dc.ad.example.com
*Service Server Name*: server.ad.example.com
*Service User Name*: test-service-user@ad.example.com

I use this as reference invocation of ktpass command:

```
ktpass /princ SERVICE-NAME/server.ad.example.com@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
       /mapuser test-service-user@ad.example.com
       /pass * /ptype KRB5_NT_PRICIPAL /crypto AES128-SHA1
```

Output on my Test System:

```
Targeting domain controller: dc.ad.example.com
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped SERVICE-NAME/server.ad.example.com to test-service-user@ad.example.com.
Type the password for SERVICE-NAME/server.ad.example.com:
Type the password again to confirm:
Key created.
```

---

Now the questions:

- The /mapuser parameter maps the Kerberos principal to the user, is this the same as doing it with `setspn -U -S SERVICE-NAME/server.ad.example.com test-service-user`? Or is there some other mapping done too? If so how do undo that mapping?
- If I look up the test-service-user using the "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool, I see that the "User logon name" has been replaced with "SERVICE-NAME/server.ad.example.com", does that mean there is only one Kerberos principal per user possible?
- I have not specified the /out parameter -  yet it states "Key created.", does this mean it has updated the password of the test-service-user or has a key been stored somewhere else (where?)?
- What does "legacy password setting method" mean?